# Google App Script no longer have "Allow anyone to access" option when deploy to web app

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a couple of google app script that reads and writes to a google spreadsheet

I used to deploy the script as a service to allow anyone to access, I allow "invoke as me"

Recently, I notice that the interface has changed to "deploy as web app"

However, now there is no option to "allow anyone to access". There is only 2 options to run the script either "only me" or "only anyone in domain"

Has Google changed the policy to not allow anyone to access scripts?

Or have I done anything wrong? Please advise

I really need the scripts to run publicly

urgent. thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Here's what I did:

1. Go to the control panel of your Google Apps Account ([instructions here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=182076))
2. Select the Settings tab
3. On the left, under Services, select Drive & Docs
4. In Sharing Options, select "Users can share documents outside this organization" (I've left the "Warn users..." check box blank)
5. Also in Sharing Options, I've selected "Private" under Document Visibility but I'm not certain that's necessary. You could try with/without.

Go back to Deploy as webapp in your script project and you should now see "allow anyone to access" - at least I do in mine!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation seems to be quite clear on this matter, you haven't done anything wrong :

*After you write the script, you publish it as a service. During the publishing process, you define who has access to the script.
In a Google Apps domain, you can publish the script so that **only you have access** or so that **everyone in the domain has access.**
In a Google consumer account, you can publish the script so that only you have access or so that everyone in the world has access.*

If you need anyone outside your google apps domain to access your spreadsheet data you could install the script on a consumer account (that has sharing permission on the domain spreadsheet) and publish it from there.