# Why can't I grant "Anyone" access when deploying script via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, contentful

this question might be pretty basic compared to some of the other posts I've read, but was hoping someone might have some insight:

My organization (A music school) is gearing up to launch a new website using the Contentful platform, and in order to collect information from the website's class sign-up forms on our Google drive, we have been given a bit of code that will let the two communicate. Unfortunately, when I try to deploy this bit of code and set the permissions, the only options appear to be for myself, and the organization. I have been told that in order for folks to enter data into the forms, it needs to be set to "Anyone".

I've gone into the google Admin console to mess with our Drive permissions, but all of the relevant "anyone"-s seem to be already toggled on...Am I missing something here? Does Apps Script keep their permissions options somewhere else?

Anyway, hope that that all made sense...Would be very grateful for any suggestions--thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, just to make sure the option is not available, can make sure you went through these steps:

- Deploy (blue button top right)
- New deployment
- Cog settings icon
- Wep app
- Added some description
- Open the dropdown "Who has access"
- Can you see the option "Anyone"? (screenshot below)

[Dropdown "Who has access" when deploying an app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbXZi.png)

If you still don't see the option maybe you will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199701/google-app-script-no-longer-have-allow-anyone-to-access-option-when-deploy-to).